# Send values to Google Analytics via PHP script

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am using the following script to send data from a form to google analytics:

```
if ($result){
        $var_utmac = 'UA-0000000-0';
        $var_utmhn = 'my-site.com'; // domain
        $var_utmn = rand(1000000000,9999999999); // random number
        $var_cookie = rand(10000000,99999999); //random cookie number
        $var_random = rand(1000000000,2147483647); //number under 2147483647
        $var_today = time();
        $var_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //referer url
        if ($var_referer == '') { $var_referer = '-'; }
        $var_uservar='-'; // no user-defined
        $var_utmp= $_POST['REQUEST_URI'].'data_'.  htmlentities($_POST['dataone']).'_'.htmlentities($_POST['datatwo']); // folder called no_jstracker to segment nojavascript visitors
        $urchinUrl='http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=3&utmn=' . $var_utmn . '&utme=&utmcs=-&utmsr=-&utmsc=-&utmul=-&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=-&utmhn=' . $var_utmhn . '&utmhid=' . $var_utmn . '&utmr=' . $var_referer . '&utmp=' . $var_utmp . '&utmac=' . $var_utmac . '&utmcc=__utma%3D' . $var_cookie . '.' . $var_random . '.' . $var_today . '.' . $var_today . '.' . $var_today . '.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D' . $var_cookie . '.' . $var_today . '.2.2.utmcsr%3D_SOURCE_%7Cutmccn%3D_CAMPAIGN_%7Cutmcmd%3D_MEDIUM_%7Cutmctr%3D_KEYWORD_%7Cutmcct%3D_CONTENT_%3B%2B__utmv%3D' . $var_cookie . '.' . $var_uservar . '%3B';
        echo ' <img src="' . $urchinUrl . '" border="0" />';
    }
```

While the data is being sent successfully there is one issue and that is that analytics doesn't show some of the data correctly i.e. for campaign data ist just shoes "*CAMPAIGN*" for keyword it shows "*KEYWORD*". It is clear where this happens in the script but am not sure how to fix it. Ideally of course analytics should populate that with its own data.

Any suggestions whether this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is happen because you hard coded "CAMPAIGN" value. instead of that assign value for campaign.

```
$CAMPAIGN='facebook';
$KEYWORD='testing';
$urchinUrl='http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=3&utmn=' . $var_utmn . '&utme=&utmcs=-&utmsr=-&utmsc=-&utmul=-&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=-&utmhn=' . $var_utmhn . '&utmhid=' . $var_utmn . '&utmr=' . $var_referer . '&utmp=' . $var_utmp . '&utmac=' . $var_utmac . '&utmcc=__utma%3D' . $var_cookie . '.' . $var_random . '.' . $var_today . '.' . $var_today . '.' . $var_today . '.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D' . $var_cookie . '.' . $var_today . '.2.2.utmcsr%3D_SOURCE_%7Cutmccn%3D'.$CAMPAIGN.'%7Cutmcmd%3D_MEDIUM_%7Cutmctr%3D'.$KEYWORD.'%7Cutmcct%3D_CONTENT_%3B%2B__utmv%3D' . $var_cookie . '.' . $var_uservar . '%3B';
```

for more details about [Google Analytics Cookies](http://www.tutkiun.com/2011/04/a-google-analytics-cookie-explained.html)

Comment: Thank you for the info. But I don't want to hard code the values but instead have Google fill them in so I would know for example if someone came via Adwords or organic search.